# iPhone camera and streaming

Tags: iphone, camera, streaming

I'd like to capture the camera's video from the iPhone and send the video stream to a server.
 I know that I must use AVFoundation, and I've heard about AVCaptureVideoOutput which allows me to handle each frame from the camera. 
The question is : how can iI send each frame to a server?

Thanks

Comment: Pick your desired streaming format, then ask about that one?

Answer (score 0):

AV Foundation will do everything that you need to do to gain access to the camera's raw data. Once you have those frames, it's up to you to decide what to do with them, including serializing them for streaming to your server.